# How do you open an EVO 3D to access the battery or SD card?

Tags: battery, hardware, htc-evo-3d

How do I open an EVO 3D? I have one right here and I tried googling it, but I dont have the manual and it isn't intuitive. I would like to view the microSD card and switch it out at will.

Comment: i found dropping it does the trick too.

Answer (score 4):

On the bottom, near the primary mic, is a slot to "pry off" the battery cover. Be careful, of course!